# Counting values in an array w/ PHP

Tags: php

I need to perform a a task when there are some values in my array. So I used **count**

```
count($_SESSION['arrayValues'][$_SESSION['event']]);
```

And my code acts as if there's something in the array, however when I do print_r I get the following:

```
Array ( [0] => )
```

So I suppose I need to count values. Tried using **array_count_values** but it does not seem to work for me... I'm a bit confused now.

Comment: `Array ( [0] => )` means there's one element in the array, possibly an empty string. Try `var_dump` for more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count()` will do that, and just fine. I'm guessing something is wrong with your array key access. Try doing a big old:

`print_r($_SESSION)`

and make sure your keys are set up as expected and your `$_SESSION['event']` isn't being populated incorrectly. Also, you're accessing `$_SESSION['arrayValues'][$_SESSION['event']]`, not `$_SESSION['arrayValues']['event']`, whether you mean to or not.